# Scheduling scripts to run at say 8:00am and send results to excel or email

Tags: sql, teradata

Can anyone help me ? I want to

Schedule teradata sql scripts to run at say 8:00am and send results to excel or email

let's say the script is ""select contact_id, home_address from Table"" I want the output to be automatically sent in excel/csv to email of receipient, for example every 8:00am –

Comment: Event? Can you please explain?

Comment: Needs a bit more explanation : what did you do so far, any scripts on error, a start of a script maybe ?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168395/execute-sql-statement-and-send-result-to-email

Comment: Julien, let's say the script is ""select contact_id, home_address from Table"" I want the output to be automatically sent in excel/csv to email of receipient, for example every 8:00am

Comment: what is the platform you are using. is it unix? what is the scheduler you are using

Comment: Aritra, I'm using Windows. I don't even know what scheduler to use. Treat me like a novice and teach me. Thanks in advance